# Getting return type of a function pointer in parameter pack and saving it as concatenated tuple with other args

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++14, variadic

I want to define a tuple type based on passed parameter pack that will have all parameters that are not functions and in place of those that are functions just save their return type. That type will be later used for indexing in hash map so I need a method to acquire it

std::result_of seems like a solution to problem, and in my test code it works if only function pointers are passed. But in my use case one may also pass other basic types and that throws "error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of’" even though i added std::conditional check

```
template <typename ...Args>
using tuple_cat_t = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<Args>()...));

template <typename ...Args>
void eval(Args... args) {
    using tuple_t = std::tuple<Args...>;
    using pattern_t = tuple_cat_t<
        typename std::conditional <
        std::is_pointer<Args>::value && std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<Args>::type>::value,
        std::tuple < std::result_of_t<Args&&()> > ,
        std::tuple<Args>
        >::type...
    >;
}

int fn(){ return 5; }   
int main(){
    eval(fn,fn); //all good, pattern type is std::tuple<int, int>
    eval(5,fn); //comilation error
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're evaluating the metafunction too eagerly. The `result_of` part is evaluated for the `int` too.

You should rearrange the conditional such that what you're selecting is a metafunction instead of a type, and then evaluate that:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template <typename Arg>
using maybe_eval = typename std::conditional_t<
    std::is_pointer<Arg>::value && std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<Arg>::type>::value,
    std::result_of<Arg&&()>,
    identity<Arg>
    >::type;

using pattern_t = tuple_cat_t<std::tuple<maybe_eval<Args>>...>;
```

Note that I'm using *both* `conditional_t` *and* `type`

Comment: That solved the problem and makes perfect sense! Thanks for clearing things up